# Does MongoDB bulk update work for fields which don't exist

Tags: java, mongodb, bulkinsert, morphia

I am trying to add an extra field to a collection of objects, the class is called Product.

I've printed the number of updates results with `results.getUpdatedCount()` and this gives the proper result, so it looks like something is happening.

So I suspect that you cannot do a "bulk update" on a new field. I.e. it thinks it's doing something hence no error is thrown, but in actual fact nothing happens. But this seems pretty unlikely, do you have any ideas?

The morphia docs I've used are here: https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia/wiki/Updating

My code looks like this:

```
public void updateStatusToOld(String val){

    Datastore ds = Dao.instance().getDatabase();
    UpdateOperations<Product> ops;
    Query<Product> query = ds.createQuery(Product.class).field("key").equal(val);
    ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(Product.class).set("status", "OLD");
    UpdateResults<Product> results = ds.update(query, ops);

}
```

Comment: If you are just trying to add a new field with the same value to all documents then you don't need "Bulk Update" ( which this is not anyway ), but you just need the ["multi"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) parameter. Otherwise an update just updates "one" or the first match found

Comment: Thanks, I've made ..., "OLD"); into ..., "OLD", true); but this isn't having any affect -- the strange thing is I get a result with results.getUpdatedCount(), that says '1643' records are being updated (whether I add true or not). This is what is confusing me.

Comment: It's legacy API and the implementation in the driver. It's the "matched" count and not the "updated" count being returned. The newer actual "Bulk" methods return a more structured result with more detail.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I need to update my mongo and morphia drivers